# Trouble connecting repository to Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, git, xcode4, bitbucket

I have made a private repository on BitBucket.

This repo should be used by me and a colleague, and therefore I want to connect it to Xcode.
So when I start Xcode I press on **Connect to a repository** and paste the following link:

ssh://bitbucket.org/ourteam/repository.git

Xcode correctly says, that authentication is needed.
My user is admin of the repo, and can connect to it.
I tested it with **SourceTree** and it works.

However, when Xcode prompts for the username and password, I always get an authentication error.

Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

---

### Running on

Xcode Version 4.5.2 (4G2008a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be that the link isn't right. I was getting the similar sort of error as you. What I did to fix it was:

1. Go to Bitbucket.com
2. Go to your repo
3. Click on the "clone" button(next to "Fork")
4. Select either SSH or HTTPS
5. Copy just the location, without "git clone"
6. Open XCode, and click on Connect to a repository
7. Paste the location
8. It might ask if you want to add to your keychain
9. Select where in the filesystem you want the project
10. It might complain about the certificate here
11. Click Clone

Worked for me, I used HTTPS, but SSH should work the same way. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Dustin, however you only have read-access then. Xcode creates a local repo for your, by pushing it, the changes won't be committed to the server.

Comment: It's actually pretty easy, you just have to clone the repo with read/write access :)